# replace specific char of a string using sed using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have to replace a specific line of a file with some other value. for eg: I have a file with content as below:

```
request.timing=0/10 * * * * * ?
```

Now, I want to replace 10 (or to be specific, any value in that place) with a dynamic value.  Eg, if I want to replace that with 20, the file should be updated as:

```
request.timing=0/20 * * * * * ?
```

Can someone help me? I am using sed as below:

```
sed -i "s/request.timing=0\/??/request.timing=0\/$poller"
```

where poller is dynamic value we pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ echo 'request.timing=0/10 * * * * * ?' |
sed -r 's:(request.timing=0/)[0-9]+:\1135:'
request.timing=0/135 * * * * * ?

$ poller="135"
$ echo 'request.timing=0/10 * * * * * ?' |
sed -r 's:(request.timing=0/)[0-9]+:\1'"$poller"':'
request.timing=0/135 * * * * * ?
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must check the characters the variable `$poller` has, because `sed` can interpret any character in there as a special one. Once you have checked that, use a `sed` separator which is **not** inside `$poller`. Let's suppose we can use `/`:

```
sed -r 's/(request.timing=0\/)[0-9]{2}/\1'"$poller"'/g'
```

#### How does it works

`-r` option activates *extended regular expressions* so you can use things like `[0-9]{2}`, and with `( ... )` you're capturing the string to use in the *replacement* site.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you were having troubles is that `?` is not valid in the regular expression. Use `.` instead. `?` is used to say the previous character may be present 0 or 1 times.

```
sed -i "s/request.timing=0\/../request.timing=0\/$poller"
```

(That's not to say the other answers aren't correct!)

Comment: Hi.. I tried both answers @miken32 and Ed Morton ..both worked..   Thanks for the swift response.